# SWRevealViewController NOT working

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I simply implemented [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EFfPT3UeWs) until  minute 8:35 , and it did not work.

```
 import Foundation
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("open")
    Open.target = self.revealViewController()
    Open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
     print("open2")
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

However, its worth to note. I am getting to this page after splash screen page.And below how am doing it

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)                                
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Navigate") as! UINavigationController                            
                        //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

From Splashscontroller  i am calling to go main.storyboard.
Navigate, I click on navigation controller and give it storyboardid Navigate.

I get to the page, with open button..but no right reveal controller opens when i click on it.

Comment: Am trying to instantiateViewController(withidentifier: "SWRevealViewController" getting black screen

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your appdelegate  "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method's code as below

// create viewController code...

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 

let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(""Navigate") as! UINavigationController

let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Left") as! LeftSideMenuViewController 

let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(SailDataViewController:mainViewController , LeftSideMenuViewController : leftViewController)

   self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

 UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

please check in your class name , because I haven't run this code . But in my project it is working.

Comment: it is in swift2.3 , please make some changes for swift 3

Comment: SlideMenuController does not exist, in the library.

Comment: just focus on the references and classes in my code accordingt to your requirements .